# Error 405: Method not allowed

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, http-status-code-405

I have my json data which i need to be posted to a url or just update the json data in one of my site urls. But i get the 405 error.
This is my code.

```
    $.post("details", {name: "John", location: "us"});
```

Comment: Are you sure the URL you're posting to allows for `POST` requests? Maybe you're supposed to do `PUT` or `PATCH`.

Comment: not much hope for help without sharing some details of the server side

Comment: I am hosting it from SAP Hana cloud platform. I am not sure about server configurations.

Answer (score 3):

405 errors can be traced to **configuration of the Web server** and security governing access to the content of the Web site. It seems that the server to which you are sending the Post request(your Site's server) has been configured to block Post request. 
You can configure your server to allow the Post request. For more details, go to http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My failure was in the sort of the request:

I had a "POST" request in my mockserver.js:

```
  {method: "POST", path: "app/Registration/sendRegisData.*", response: function (xhr) { xhr.respondFile(200, {}, "../testdata/getUser.json"); } }
```

and tried to use this path with a "PUT"-call in my controller:

```
    $.ajax({
                url: "z_dominosapp/Registration/sendRegisData",
                type: "POST",
                data: data
            }).done(function(){.......});
```

First, I didn't noticed it and was wondering why only the "fail" part of the ajax call was called. Maybe this careless mistake of me helps you in any way.